# How to point a domain name from Name.com to my home web server?

Tags: home-server, hostname, domain-name

I have a fully working home web server on Fedora 15 at `http://24.109.247.176/`

I want to have my domain which is on Name.com to be used for my home web server.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the domain and then change the DNS records to point to that ip address. Is it static or dynamic?

Free alternative: open an account with dyndns.org and you can select from ~20 domains and have a your domain.theirdomain.com

For Example: In GoDaddy, I have a domain.me. I want to point this to my home IP address 74.x.x.x. I registered my domain.me address and now I can edit the DNS to point www.domain.me to 74.x.x.x

[image]

Comment: You will also want to make sure that your ISP allows web servers with their home plan. You can usually get away with port 80 (http) but most often they will crack down on ssh, FTP, smtp, etc.

Comment: in my experience port 80 is more often blocked. also, most mail providers reject e mails from home/dynamic ips

Comment: I already have my home web server running, I just need a domain on it so people dont have to type my IP

Answer (score 3):

If your ip address is static, its a simple matter of going to your registrar's config page and setting an A record for your ip address.

If its a dynamic ip address, and your provider dosen't support dynamic dns, i'd suggest using [zoneedit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) to handle your dns - its free for up to two DNS zones, and allows you to use dynamic dns clients.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? I'm really noob when it comes to this stuff:P My IP is Dynamic, but it can also be set to static.